# Function argument declaration without type

Tags: excel, vba

For a class, I have stumbled upon this VBA code for an excel sheet. It shows the implementation of a function, where the parameter has not been declared to be of any type. When it is called, a `String` is used as this parameter.

```
Option Explicit

' The weird function
Function isXorEmpty(testvalue) As Boolean
    If testvalue = "x" Or testvalue = "" Then
        isXorEmpty = True
    Else
        isXorEmpty = False
    End If
End Function 

' Button click handler
Sub verify_input_conformity_Click()
    Dim testvalue As String
    testvalue = Sheets(0).Cells(0, SOME_COLUMN_CONSTANT)

    If Not isXorEmpty(testvalue) Then
        Call SomeFunction() 
    End If

End Sub
```

The code works correctly within Excel, i.e., it detects incorrect input values.

I have searched the internet but have come to no conclusion what this language feature of VBA is called, and how exactly it behaves when a argument type is left out like that. Can someone point me to documentation of this?

Comment: A variable without a type (including arguments) default to the [Variant type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/variant-data-type).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> Function isXorEmpty(testvalue) As Boolean
> ```

This is implicitly equivalent to this:

```
Public Function isXorEmpty(ByRef testvalue As Variant) As Boolean
```

The `Variant` is implicitly converted to `Variant/String` (twice) for the two string comparisons; a run-time error could happen if anything other than a `String` (actually, anything *that can't be implicitly converted* to one) is passed through `testValue`.

Moreover, the implicit `ByRef` means it's possible for `isXorEmpty` to re-assign that parameter in its body, and thereby introduce subtle bugs in the calling code.

A better signature would be:

```
Public Function isXorEmpty(ByVal testvalue As String) As Boolean
```

That said the condition body is assigning a Boolean literal in both conditional branches - it can be rephrased as follows:

```
isXorEmpty = (testvalue = "x" Or testvalue = "")
```